# Recurrence for quaternary search algorithm

Tags: computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

I have to come up with the recurrence for the quaternary search algorithm.  My initial thought is $T(n) = 4T(\frac{n}{4})+c$ because I examine all 4 subproblems, and each is 1/4 the size of the entire array.  But this can't be right because that yields a complexity of O(n).  I looked on google and the complexity of quaternary searches are supposed to be $log_4n$, but I don't know what the recurrence would be to get me that complexity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/64268/755, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1954101/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm closing this question as because it was [cross-posted](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64268/recurrence-for-quaternary-search-algorithm) and received an additional answer on [cs.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct recursion formula is $T(n)=T(\frac{n}{4})+cT(n)=T(n4)+c$, which yields $O(lgn)$. Because the base is 4 here, for quaternary searches it becomes $O(log_4n)$.